# Binding energy vs. ionization energy

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I am studying binding energy in the context of photoelectric spectroscopy, and I came across a graph of relative numbers of electrons vs binding energy (in units of megajoules per mole). The element in question is lithium. My chemistry resource (Khan academy, to be precise) noted that the binding energy for the furthest right peak corresponds to the binding energy for the electron in the 2s subshell, and that this is also equal to the first ionization energy. However, they go on to say that the the binding energy of the second peak is not equal to the second ionization energy, since the electrons are held more tightly by the nucleus once the outermost electron is removed. I actually have two questions about this. First, why are they more tightly held once the outermost electron is removed? Is the electric field of the protons somehow getting weakened by the presence of the outer electron? I don't think this would be the case, based on my understanding of electric fields. So what is the explanation?

My other question is why the binding energy is different from the ionization energy? Is it because the electrons are removed all at once versus them being removed one-by-one? Or is there some nuance to this situation I am not seeing?

I found a question on this website that seems to be asking a similar thing, but no one answered it. Here's the link to it anyway.

[Chemistry: What's the difference between "binding energy" and "ionization energy"?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/104036/chemistry-whats-the-difference-between-binding-energy-and-ionization-energy)

Thanks in advance for the help.[image: photoelectron spectrum for lithium]

Comment: Isn't just one question? Or better, the question should be why PES can probe two energies "at once"? The rest is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

First some basics....

Lithium has three electrons.

> $\ce{Li}$ electronic configuration: $1s^22s^1$
>
> $\ce{Li -> Li+ + e-\quad\quad\mathrm{Ionization\ Energy= 0.520\ MJ/mol}}$
>
> $\ce{Li+}$ electronic configuration: $1s^2$
>
> $\ce{Li+ -> Li^2+ + e-\quad\quad\mathrm{Ionization\ Energy= 7.298\ MJ/mol}}$
>
> $\ce{Li^2+}$ electronic configuration: $1s^1$
>
> $\ce{Li^2+ -> Li^3+ + e-\quad\quad\mathrm{Ionization\ Energy=11.815\ MJ/mol}}$
>
> $\ce{Li^3+}$ electronic configuration: $1s^0$, i.e. no electrons
>
> [Ionization energies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energies_of_the_elements_(data_page)) from Wikipedia

Thus the different ionization reactions remove the electrons from the outer most to the inner most electrons.

Below is an another image of the idealized spectra of lithium that has the binding energies stated. (from https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/09-105/S98Slides9.html)

[image]

$\mathrm{Binding\ Energy= 0.52\ MJ/mol}$ corresponds to $\ce{Li -> Li+ + e-}$
or $1s^2 2s^1\ce{->} 1s^2$, hence the first ionization energy of a Li atom.

However $\mathrm{Binding\ Energy= 6.26\ MJ/mol}$ corresponds to $\ce{Li -> Li+ + e-}$
or $1s^2 2s^1\ce{->} 1s^12s^1$, which is not the first or second ionization energy of a Li atom. Rather it is the binding energy of the 1s orbital in a neutral lithium atom.

Hence the photoelectron spectra is called the binding energy spectra because that is what it measures. Note that the sweep of the spectra would not have to cover the ionization energy. For example the spectra could have been taken from 5 MJ/mol to 100 MJ/mol.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the questions as well as those in the linked post lie in the following:

> the second peak is not equal to the second ionization energy, since the electrons are held more tightly by the nucleus once the outermost electron is removed

It is worth reviewing the basic principle of the PES experiment: you irradiate the  sample with high energy photons (with energy well above electron binding energies) and determine the count and kinetic energy of emitted electrons. From the kinetic energy and the energy of the incident radiation you compute the *binding energy* by simple arithmetic:
$$E_B=h\nu -E_K$$
This data you report as a spectrum of counts versus binding energy. The binding energy is the amount of energy required to eject a particular electron transforming it from a bound state in a specific orbital into a free (unbound) electron (in theory, with zero kinetic energy once it is infinitely removed from its source atom).

The question is, how might a measured binding energy differ from an ionization energy? Ionization energies are equal to or greater than binding energies. The binding energy of a valence electron is equal to the *first* ionization energy, which corresponds to the same event of ejecting the first valence electron. The problem is that *second* ionization energies are defined as the energies required to eject a second electron, after a first ejection has occurred, that is, from an ion. The second electron will occupy a lower energy orbital (it is more strongly bound). In the PES experiment, an electron in an inner shell (non-valence) can be observed directly, without a prior first-ionization step. The energy to remove the inner shell electron from the neutral atom (the so-called binding energy) is not the same as required to eject a second electron (the so-called second ionization energy).

The reason it takes more energy to remove a second or later electron is because electron-electron repulsion raises the energy of each and every electron in an atom. The usual convention is that (in general) bringing an electron closer to the positively charged nucleus lowers its energy, and bringing two electrons closer to each other increases their energy. Electrons repel each other, therefore if you have more electrons in an atom (the nucleus otherwise remaining the same) the ejected electron will be "pushed" away a little harder by the other electrons and it will take a lesser external energy input to expel the electron.

Comment: Don't you mean that the electron-electron repulsion decreases the energy of each and every electron? Unless I have it wrong still. The reason I say that it should decrease the energy is that it appears that the second or third ionization energy is greater than the binding energy for those same electrons. Sorry if I still have it wrong

Comment: @Aaron23 I edited my answer in an attempt to explain. It's a matter of convention. Adding electrons to an atom increases electron-electron repulsion (increase in energy), whereas removing an electron reduces the energy of remaining electrons.