# Why is the entire 3p sublevel peak shifted to the right on a PES of Sulfur vs Phosphorus?

Tags: spectrophotometry

Edit: Please see answer. I am going to leave the question here in case someone else has a similar misunderstanding.

I am currently a student in AP Chemistry. I was working on an assignment with these two PES spectrums.

[image]

One of the questions is:

> Explain why peak E in the sulfur spectrum is shifted slightly right comparted to peak E in the phosphorus spectrum.

The answer key says:

> Sulfur has four electrons in the outermost shell, compared to three electrons in that shell for phosphorus. Electrons repel each other so there is a slight reduction in ionization energy because of the repulsion effects of the surrounding electrons. The additional sulfur electron occupies a half-filled 3p orbital, thus causing electron-electron repulsion.

I would think that one of the electrons in the full 3p orbital would be first to go, so after that, there would be no full 3p orbital. Then, since sulfur has another proton in its nucleus than phosphorus, the attraction would be stronger so therefore the ionization energy would be higher to remove the remaining 3 electrons in the 3p sublevel.

In summary, I think there should be a peak to the right of the Phosphorus E peak with a height of 1 electron, and then a peak to the left of Phosphorus E peak with a height of 3 electrons. The same could be applied to the C peak: why is it one peak instead of two distinct peaks(one when it has full orbitals, one when it has half-filled orbitals).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138792/discussion-on-question-by-jb0-why-is-the-entire-3p-sublevel-peak-shifted-to-the).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My question was rooted in a misunderstanding with the process of Photoelectron spectroscopy.

Originally, I thought that photons were beamed until all electrons were lost from an atom, which would report the first, second, third, etc. ionization energy, where the second ionization energy starts with the +1 cation, and the third with the +2 cation, etc.

However, Photoelectron spectroscopy actually finds the binding energy for each electron in the ground state. The reason it can do this is that:

1. it uses a photon energy that can knock off any electron in the atoms, and
2. since there is a large amounts of atoms and finite photons, very few atoms get struck by a photon and lose even a single electron, so it would be even more rare for an atom that already lost an electron to be struck by a photon and lose another electron.

For others struggling with this concept, the answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/140217/72973) does a good job of explaining the difference between first ionization energy and binding energy.
[Here](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/ap-chemistry-beta/x2eef969c74e0d802:atomic-structure-and-properties/x2eef969c74e0d802:photoelectron-spectroscopy/a/photoelectron-spectroscopy) is a Khan Academy link that explains the process of Photoelectron spectroscopy in simple terms.

Thank you to [@Karsten](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/72973/karsten) for helping with this question!

Answer (score 0):

Greetings fellow AP Chem student:

The general trend for Sulfur is that, yes, as you identified earlier, all of its peaks are shifted right because effective nuclear charge is greater than phosphorus (and thus corresponding ionization energies are higher). However, E is the exception because firstly, it is in the outermost energy shell/level, and it prone to additional nuclear shielding that causes those electrons to feel less electrostatic attractions than electrons that penetrate the core shell (due to the co-electron shielding that one extra 3p electron adds to the mix), making the respective effective nuclear charges for sulfur and phosphorus about the same FOR THAT SPECIFIC SUBSHELL, **despite the fact that sulfur has one more proton**. The answer key is correct, since for peak E 3p subshell sulfur has an additional electron, and thus additional electron-electron repulsions in THAT SUBSHELL. The COMBINATION of a localized nuclear charge in the outer shell and additional electron-electron repulsions causes the ionization energy of electrons in the 3p subshell in sulfur to have slightly lower ionization energy than that of phosphorus, which doesn't have to deal with as much electron-electron repulsions in the same subshell but with about the same effective nuclear charge. Hence the deviation of peak E from the normal trend.

I am from New York, by the way.

School starts about a month later! ;)